# Why does Elias' younger version look more like Anthony rather than Elias?

Tags: character, person-of-interest

In Season 1 Episode 19 "Flesh_and_Blood" of Person of Interest, we see Elias in flashback scenes. His style of standing, way of talking, hair style and face resembles Anthony (Elias' foster brother, friend and second in command). Why is this?

Although they are foster brothers, they are not related by blood.
At first, when they started showing the flashback, I thought it's Anthony's backstory. But then that young man was shown as son of Don Morretti.